Binary combination - find individual parts from sum
Lets say we are having 4 "N" bit values, and in each of them there is exactly 1 10-bit pattern of "1000000001" somewhere (x can be 0 or 1, and it will be exactly N-10) -
  xxx1000000001xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx + (x can be 0 or 1)
  xxxx1000000001xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx +
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1000000001xxxxxxx +
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1000000001 
---------------------------------------
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy (y can be 0 or 1)

Now, if we are given the sum bit pattern (yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy)
and the constituent bit parts (as a continuous bit string) -
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy and
xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Can we find the 4 original full bit parts from the above data.
The brute force approach would be to try 1 "1000000001" pattern within each bit-position in the "N-10" string, sum the resulting 4 "N" bit strings, and compare it against the sum pattern (yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy)
until equality is achieved.
However it would take a lot of combinations.
Example if N=256, the brute force approach would involve about 246 x 246 x 246 x 246 calculations.
Is there a better way to find the components with an efficient approach.

Can you describe more what the input "the constituent bit parts" is?

constituent bit parts are the 4 set of "x" bits as shown in the example above

If you have all the "x" bits, why care about the "y" value at all?

Oh, you mean you get the bits which are NOT in the "1000000001" substrings?

the "x" bits are given as a continuous string, so we are not aware where exactly will the "1000000001" bit belong in the original bit string.. we have to try to insert it at each bit-position and try to equate to the sum value.

We can reduce from the brute force cost a lot by considering the lowest $k$ bits at a time, working our way up. For example, if adding the $x$ strings with no insertions and subtracting the $y$ string value gives an odd number, there must be at least one insertion at the very right end. If adding the $x$ strings and subtracting $y$ gives a number not divisible by $4$, there must be at least one insertion at the right end or just before the last digit.
So a somewhat simple algorithm could look like the following:
We can consider the input to be

the number $Y$ formed from the $n$ "y" bits, since no other bit string manipulations matter for them.
four bit strings $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, each containing $(n-10)$ "x" bits, since a single input of length $4(n-10)$ is simple to split.

Call a "generalized index" a value which is either a number from $0$ to $n-10$ or else the value "$\mathrm{Unknown}$". The "test bit string" for a number index $I_m$ and bit string $x_m$ is formed from the first $(n-I_m-10)$ bits of $x_m$, then the substring "$1000000001$", then the remaining $I_m$ final bits of $x_m$. The "test bit string" for an $\mathrm{Unknown}$ index is the bit string $x_m$. (Yes, it's shorter.) During the algorithm below, an index of $\mathrm{Unknown}$ will mean some index to be determined but larger than the variable $k$.
Call a "partial solution" a tuple $(I_1,I_2,I_3,I_4)$ of four generalized indices.

Initialize a variable set $S$ of partial solutions with the single element $(\mathrm{Unknown}, \mathrm{Unknown}, \mathrm{Unknown}, \mathrm{Unknown})$.

For each index $k$ from $0$ to $n-10$:

For each partial solution in $S$, add all possible partial solutions where some subset of the $\mathrm{Unknown}$ values are replaced with $k$. So if the existing solution has $j$ $\mathrm{Unknown}$ values, this adds $2^j-1$ more partial solutions.

For each partial solution in $S$, check whether the bottom $k+1$ bits match the sum: For each $m$ from $1$ to $4$, let $X_m$ be the number from binary interpretation of the test bit string built from $I_m$ and $x_m$. If $X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4-Y \not \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{k+1}}$, remove the partial solution from $S$.



Discard any remaining solutions in $S$ which contain any $\mathrm{Unknown}$ values. The remaining solutions in $S$ are the possible positions for inserting the $1000000001$ substrings.


There could be all sorts of tweaks to this depending on what's efficient, whether you want all valid solutions or just any one solution, and whether you want the best average performance or best worst-case performance. For one, it might be better to check any potential solution with four numbers and no $\mathrm{Unknown}$ against the entire $Y$ immediately, or (especially if $n$ is large) to partially compute only the lowest bits of the $X_m$ numbers and continue checking them one additional bit at a time.
